# Cannot download file in SharePoint Online using CURL

Tags: sharepoint-online, curl

Hi we are using curl command line on our on-prem environment to download files but when we tried it in SharePoint Online it is no longer working. Is there any way or workaround on this one?

This is just only for the end user with contribute/read-only permission.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You can try using Powershell and PnP. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/download-documents-from-sharepoint-using-pnp-powershell. Official MS docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Hi that is only possible for user with tenant access. We only need to enable it on normal users.

Comment: Then, for a normal user, you can map the library to explorer view and directly copy from there. And I don't think you need to have tenant access permissions for using PnP. You only need to have permissions to the site and library to read.

Comment: Hi thanks im already checking out pnp. but i cant download the file

Comment: Its Says File Not Found.

Comment: Can you please post the code you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CURL is no longer supported in SharePoint Online and I just  tried using SharePoint Online PNP Pnp-GetFile using PowerShell and it works.